# Problems building melodic compressed_depth_image_transport on 18.04

Tags: opencv, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following these instructions to do a source build of melodic desktop full (I want to build it with thread sanitizer because of something I'm debugging): http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source

I'm getting this error, I know it has to do something with OpenCV versions but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'compressed_depth_image_transport'
==> Building with env: '/home/tyler/workspace/ws_ros_melodic/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/tyler/workspace/ws_ros_melodic/build_isolated/compressed_depth_image_transport'
==> make -j8 -l8 in '/home/tyler/workspace/ws_ros_melodic/build_isolated/compressed_depth_image_transport'
[ 16%] Built target compressed_depth_image_transport_gencfg
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/src/codec.cpp.o
/home/tyler/workspace/ws_ros_melodic/src/image_transport_plugins/compressed_depth_image_transport/src/codec.cpp: In function ‘sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >::Ptr compressed_depth_image_transport::decodeCompressedDepthImage(const CompressedImage&)’:
/home/tyler/workspace/ws_ros_melodic/src/image_transport_plugins/compressed_depth_image_transport/src/codec.cpp:138:49: error: ‘CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED’ was not declared in this scope
         cv_ptr->image = cv::imdecode(imageData, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/src/codec.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/src/codec.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1096: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'compressed_depth_image_transport': 
  Command '['/home/tyler/workspace/ws_ros_melodic/install_isolated/env.sh', 'make', '-j8', '-l8']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354854/problems-building-melodic-compressed_depth_image_transport-on-18.04./) by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2020-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have OpenCV 3.4 or 4.x installed?

According to [ros-perception/image_transport_plugins#54](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins/issues/54) and a bunch of other Google results, those flags were renamed quite a few times between 2018 and now.

Melodic targets OpenCV 3.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 (see [Melodic Morenia (May 2018 - May 2023)](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023) in REP-3). And with that: not the upstream version, but:

> " * " means that this is not the upstream version (available on the official Operating System repositories) but a package distributed by OSRF or the community (package built and distributed on custom repositories).

You'll have to make sure you have that version *or* if you have others, CMake finds the required version first.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on 2020-06-14**:
That was it, thank you.  I have 4 installed because we are using it for a project that has another external dependency that depends on 4.  I got by this by putting CATKIN_IGNORE filles in the two packages that wouldn't build in ros as searching my code I don't think we use them.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-14**:
Seeing some of your other questions (here and on the MoveIt issue tracker(s)), I would perhaps suggest to look into using containers more.

**Comment by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on 2020-06-14**:
I do use containers when I have to, but perhaps I should use them more.